# I want, using my private API, to fetch my data but I want them to be checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, fetch-api

[image]Here's what I have so far

main.html (it's a form btw)

```
 <div class="form-group form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="region" id="US" value="US">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="US">US</label>
</div>
```

api.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const urlUS = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/regionApi/regionProduct/1")
document.getElementById('US').addEventListener('click', getRegionUS)

function getRegionUS() {
        fetch(urlUS, {
            method:'GET'
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                data.forEach(function(product){
                    output = `
                    <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="${product.productname}" id="${product.id}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="${product.id}">
                    ${product.productname}
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    `
                })
                
                document.getElementById('US').innerHTML = output
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error'))
    }

})
```

When clicking on the radio button I do get the information I am looking for in my api. What am I missing ? Why wouldn't it appear in checkboxes ? What should I try ?

Comment: You will need to append  `+=` your output inside each iteration of the `foreach`

Comment: It's not clear what is your actual issue with this code. Determined by the code, it looks like you'd get only the last product shown on the page. Can you please describe in details what you want your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: Oh I added a picture of the problem but I guess it just didnt load. i'll edit my my post @Teemu

Comment: @phuzi I added added += but I now get an error

Comment: You also appear to be trying to add your HTML ___inside___ the radio button input - which is not going to work. You will need a separate place in the HTML to add your output too.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is the problem itself really related to that API, or to JSON?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to transform the json response into checkboxes. I am able to fetch the data but that's pretty much it

Comment: See my answer for a more detailed explanation and a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a couple of issues with your code...

1. You're replacing the HTML outside the `foreach` but it only ever uses the last assignment to `output` as it is overwritten each iteration.
2. You're attempting to add the HTML ***inside*** a checkbox input element which is not allowed.

You will need to build up the HTML, adding to it each iteration, before inserting it all in to the page afterwards. You will also need somewhere else on the page to add the generated HTML. See below

*Please Note: I have used a freely available JSON API designed for supplying fake test data so I've had to change the HTML generation slightly to work with that data*

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const urlUS = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
  document.getElementById('US').addEventListener('click', getRegionUS)

  function getRegionUS() {
    fetch(urlUS, { method: 'GET' })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        let output = '';

        data.forEach(function(product) {
          output += `
                    <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="${product.name}" id="${product.id}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="${product.id}">
                    ${product.name}
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    `;
        })

        document.getElementById('productInfo').innerHTML = output;
        // console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error'))
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="region" id="US" value="US">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="US">US</label>
</div>

<div id="productInfo">Generated HTML will appear here!</div>
```

Comment: ohhhh that's what you meant !!! I appreciate your help. Thank you very much

Comment: What if I want to insert the checkboxes in a div that already exist? When i try it just replaces the entire div by the checkboxes

Comment: Then you would need/want to append using `+=` i.e. `document.getElementById('productInfo').innerHTML += output`

Answer (score 0):

This can be more elegant and DRY  - I delegate from a container here

Note I reused the JSON mock data url from the other answer.
Change the product.whatever to match your object

```js
const regions = {
  "US": 1,
  "EUR": 2
};
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('item-carousel').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    fetch(`${url}${regions[tgt.id]}`, { method: 'GET' })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        document.getElementById('productInfo').innerHTML = data.map(product => `<div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="${product.title}" id="${product.id}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="${product.id}">${product.body}</label>
                    </div>`).join('');
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="item-carousel">
  <div class="form-group form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="region" id="US" value="US">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="US">US</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="region" id="EUR" value="EUR">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="EUR">EUR</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="productInfo">Generated HTML will appear here!</div>
```

Comment: for some reasons when I click on my radio buttons it does not stay bleu and the content piles. Which gives me a huge list of checkboxes if I click on all of them. However I checked and all my input have the name : "region"

Comment: I cannot guess, what you mean. Please produce an example of the code you want and the code you have now.

Comment: can i get your email or something so I can just send you the entire project

Comment: Contact details in my profile